# How to retrieve maximum supported Image/bitmap size of device lower than API14 in Android

Tags: android, image, size, android-bitmap

The question is just simple. I know there is a method to get the maximum supported image/bitmap size on device since API 14 with

```
  canvas.getMaximumBitmapHeight();
  canvas.getMaximumBitmapWidth();
```

But how should we retrieve these maximum sizes in an API lower than 14? Any idea? I haven´t found any method in the API.